# How to get all string constants for all functions called from another function?

Tags: python

I have to collect names of all strings constants in some function.

but it gets too big, so I created some functions inside. 
May I still collecting string constants including nested?

that works:

```
def my_func():
  a = '123'

str_const = {c for c in my_func.func_code.co_consts if isinstance(c, str)}

str_const = {'123'}
```

and how to get work this?

```
def my_func():
  return my_func_2()

def my_func_2():
   a = '123'

str_const = {c for c in my_func....?}

str_const = {'123'}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How to create a set of all string constants values used in function including nested function?

Comment: There is no such thing as a constant in python. That said I believe you're looking for the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#module-inspect) module.

Comment: oh, sorry, values of all string variables inside

Answer (score -1):

You can do this recursively:

```
def get_embedded_strings(funk):
    if not isinstance(funk, types.CodeType):
        funk = funk.__code__
    for constant in funk.co_consts:
        if isinstance(constant, str):
            yield constant
        elif isinstance(constant, types.CodeType):
            for value in get_embedded_strings(constant):
                yield value
```

For example, if you have:

```
def funk1(a):
    print("a")
    def funk2(b):
        print("b")
    return funk2

list(get_embedded_strings(funk1))
# returns ["a", "funk1.<locals>.funk2", "b"]
```

Note it won't work if `funk2` is not inside `funk`. It will also include the internal name of the inner function.

Comment: This does not work for `my_func` in OP's second example.

Comment: Well, that is not an embedded string